# Bad decrypt with OpenSSL using Terminal

Tags: macos, encryption, openssl, macos-mojave

I looked into tinkering with encryption using OpenSSL on Terminal.

Using the command below I managed to encrypt a file under AES256.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -in /Users/user/desktop/filename -out /Users/user/desktop/filename
```

This command successfully encrypts my file. However when I do the decryption with the following command,

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in /Users/user/desktop/filename -out /Users/user/desktop/filename
```

The file fails to decrypt, changes the target file to a zero kB empty file, and displays the message

```
error reading input file
```

This issue does not occur if I set the decrypt output to a different file name such as

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in /Users/user/desktop/filename -out /Users/user/desktop/filename2
```

Did I violate a basic principle? I'm starting to dabble into coding and want to know why the second command does not work (since it's convenient).

This is the source I came across:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272808/how-can-i-password-protect-files-in-macos

I did some searching however could not find any information on failed decrypt that lead to the deletion of the file. I was also not able to recover the missing file(not important but was a dummy).

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you did violate a basic principle - you are writing to the same file, as you are reading from, it is more interesting why the encryption is working at all too.

Comment: @gusto2+ depending on how stdlib works it might read one bufferful before the rest gets clobbered, but on my Linux (which is not MacOS of course) the encryption output is _only_ the fixed header plus one padding block (with no real data). Lin: did you check the _size_ of the encryption result against its input, before destroying it?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The files were pdf's and Word documents. They were 65kb and 631kb. Both became zero kb after the decrypt output.

Comment: Were they 65kb and 631kb _after_ encryption but _before_ decryption? And did that encryption use the output name equal to the input name?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Apologies for the tardiness, I had to verify that again. I converted a word file and it had 631kb, now it's just 32 bytes(after using the same designation for -in and -out. When decrypted with a different designation it does not recover and drops to 'zero bytes'. At this point it's a bit of a hit & miss, and can conclude that using the same designation for -in and -out, whether encrypting or decrypting, will probably result in complete file loss.

Comment: Yes, that's consistent with my experience. Using the same file for in&out first empties the file, then reads the file, gets no data, and encrypts no data, which produces the fixed header (16 bytes) plus padding (16 bytes for AES-CBC), hence 32 bytes -- but none of your actual data.

Comment: Interesting finding regarding the 32kb size, very helpful.